# CURL not working with link in PHP, but in command line it does

Tags: php, url, curl, download

I've got a problem with my PHP script using CURL. I want to download file from another server (Probably with hotlink protection). The URL is like this: example.com/script.extension?id=12345&type=xxx&another=qwerty

When i hit that link from my website, It sends 'Referer:' in headers, so the download is not starting. (without the header it works)

I have to modify the file's name, so i've used CURL to download that to my server. When I'm doing that with that script, the file is created, but it is empty:

```php
function my_function($the_url) {

    $fp = fopen ('tmp_file.extension', 'w+');

    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $the_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",       
        CURLOPT_POST           => false,       
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",      
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => false,
        CURLOPT_REFERER        => "http://example.com/",    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,     
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $my_exec = curl_exec($ch);
    fwrite($fp, $my_exec);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

}
```

But it works well with file which is hosted on my site (eg. mysite.com/file.zip)

Also, when I run command through the shell:
$ curl -L -o file.tmp --referer http://example.com/ *full url here*
It downloaded the file properly.

What's the reason I cannot do it with my PHP function?

Comment: Have you checked for any php or curl errors?

Comment: I've got errors enabled in php.ini. Nothing shows.

Comment: What about curl errors (`curl_error`, `curl_errno`)? They aren't captured by error reporting.

Comment: These errors shouldn't be in error.log (nginx)? Becouse I've got CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1. There is no error in that logfile.